# delete folder after I use the program

Tags: c#

I create a dialog program, when I crete a picturebox for any picture of one folder, and, when I close this dialog, I whant to delete the picture box, but, I recive an exception, and this exception tell me that: The file 0.jpg is used by another process

But, so, I have tried to dispose all the picturebox ... I have tried all possible things, in my knowledge, of course...

So, my sample code is that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace delFolder
{
    public partial class FormPictureView : Form
    {
        private PictureBox pbSel = null;

        public FormPictureView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AddPictureBox();
        }

        private void AddPictureBox()
        {
            int linha = 0;
            int x = 10, y = 10;
            string pngOutputPath = @"images\";

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(pngOutputPath);
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                if (linha == 2)
                {
                    x = 10;
                    y += 360;
                    linha = 0;
                }
                PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
                pb.Name = string.Format("pb{0}", i);
                pb.Size = new Size(236, 321);
                pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
                pb.Image = Image.FromFile(string.Format("{0}{1}.jpg", pngOutputPath, i));
                pb.BackColor = Color.White;
                pb.Click += new EventHandler(pb_Click);
                pb.Tag = string.Format("{0}{1}.jpg", pngOutputPath, i);
                pb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
                panel1.Controls.Add(pb);
                x += 280;
                linha++;
            }
        }

        private void pb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (pbSel != null)
                pbSel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
            pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            pbSel = pb;
            MessageBox.Show(pb.Tag.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

and, this dialog is a MDIParent of Main form..., and, when I close this dialog, I try to delete the picture box, but, it's impossible :(
How I can solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the ImageLocation property instead of the Image property no lock on the file will be aquired and you will be able to delete the file. However the image will not be available to the PictureBox any more and a "no image" icon will be displayed.

To solve this you could copy the image into memory before deleting it:

```
string imgPath = string.Format("{0}{1}.jpg", pngOutputPath, i);
// Retrieve image from file
Image img = Image.FromFile(imgPath);
// Create new canvas to paint the picture in
Bitmap tempImg = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);
// Paint image in memory
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempImg))
{
   g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
// Assign image to PictureBox
pb.Image = tempImg;
// Dispose original image and free handles
img.Dispose();
// Delete the original file
File.Delete(imgPath);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to `Dispose()` the `Image` in the PictureBox.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `yourPictureBox.image` to `null` before deleting the image